# List facebook friends by activity

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to list facebook friends by activity (number of interactions), using the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/)

Using data from the facebook API, I would like to create a CSV file with the following columns:

```
friend_name, year_added, no_of_interactions
```

This will help me clean-up friends with whom I've not shared any activity

Comment: No, that is not possible. “Number of interactions” is not a value the API provides.

Comment: That's annoying. If number is not available, can you list by any activity. In other words, see friends whom you've had some shared activity vs. none at all?

Comment: No. Plus, you would not be able to get _any_ information about your friends via API, unless they explicitly logged in to your app and granted it permissions. So forget about it, what you want here, is not feasible.

Comment: Ok. However, "get any information about your friends via API", that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to get info about activity on my own content. After x time if they're not interacting with my content (e.g. commenting on, or liking my posts) or sending messages prune the friend list to make space for new connections.

Comment: Or how does facebook intend you maintain a friend list over time, am I missing some other obvious approach?

Comment: _“I'm trying to get info about activity on my own content.”_ - you won’t be able to get any information relating to specific friends that way either, if they did not previously grant your app permissions. _“Seems rather pointless to keep around friends after x time if they're not interacting with my content (e.g. commenting on, or liking my posts) or sending messages.”_ - seems a rather weird definition of “friendship” to begin with.

Comment: I see you quoted me before I could edit the comment to clarify my thoughts. To be clear, in real life I don't expire friendships. Most of my friends I've know for ages. But facebook is a weird ecosystem, and having friends around that just lurk is a bit creepy don't you think?

Comment: “A bit creepy” in relation to Facebook, makes me want to go for a “comes with the territory” response right away :-) Fact is, Facebook does not provide any such rankings, API endpoints or other tools, to determine any such metric that you are interested in here.  If you want to clean up your friend list, then you’ll have to do that manually, and decide there and then, based on your own memories of your interactions with specific people – or the lack thereof.

Comment: I can follow that logic. However, the practical reality of manually going through the list, is that it makes me spend more time on a platform that I wish would just blend into the background. In real life friendship (mostly) does not end with there and then adjudication, it fades away over time

Answer (score 0):

Doing exactly what I asked in the question is not possible. However, what I wanted to avoid was sharing all my previous posts (with everyone I'm friends with on facebook) indefinitely.

A better approach, using the built in lists

- Keep existing visibility setting on all my posts
- Add all friends to the restricted list
- Tag individuals on friends only posts
- Post publicly to reach all friends

Related question: [Is there a way to list all facebook friends in the restricted list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70459616/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-facebook-friends-in-the-restricted-list)